# Getline not storing integer properly

Tags: c++, getline

```
string line;
int input;

           stringstream linestream;
           cout << "\nEnter integer: ";
           getline(cin,line);                                                                       
           cout << "\nNumber is << line;
```

when i'm trying to print the String line: i'm getting the entered no plus some unknown numbers
for eg. if i enter 951 the output would be 951 289792 some garbage 
and i don't want to use integer. And there is no cin>> statement b4 this code

Comment: See example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: Perhaps a close-quote would help.

Comment: Is this a copy of your real code? If not, please edit the question posting the actual code. There is an edit button under your post.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me,

```
//stringstream linestream;
//extract to string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

main ()
{
  std::string line;
  //int input;

  std::cout << "Enter integer: ";
  std::getline(std::cin,line);
  std::cout << "Number is " << line << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```